# How to use code assist in Eclipse with ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, code-assist

Usually when we use Eclipse IDE, it can assist us with related functions/variables, checking the compilation errors automatically.

Now I want to use Ant to manage the compilation and deployment process. After adding import instruction in build.xml, I can compile and run it with an Ant builder. But the problem is, when coding, the Eclipse editor cannot give code suggestions and always complains that I don't import some libraries which added in build.xml.

How to make the Eclipse editor give code suggestion and checking compilation errors based on settings in build.xml with a ant builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version of eclipse works fine for code completion and syntax checking. Maybe yours is turned off? Check under Window > Preferences > Ant > Editor and then on the Problems tab make sure that 'Ignore all buildfile problems' is turned off.

There are also some content assist options around that area - mine are all turned on.

I'm using SCS 2.5.0.RELEASE, which sits on top of eclipse 3.6.1.r361